# I cannot convert str to int because of the error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is my task.
Given a string consisting of n digits (single digits), between costs n-1 characters of operations, each of which can be either + or -. Calculate the value of this expression. The program must print the result of the calculation of this expression
Here is my code but it doesn't work

```
a = "1++++5++++3----2----9".replace("++++", "+").replace("----", "-")
print(int(str(a)))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1+5+3-2-9'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, in order to evaluate an expression you have to use the `eval()` function.

*Side Note*: *The `replace()` method returns a `str`. So, you don't have to cast it to `str`*

So, the resultant code is as follows

```py
a = "1++++5++++3----2----9".replace("++++", "+").replace("----", "-")
print(eval(a))
```

Output

```
-2
```